# '\"node build\bundle.js\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I setup some scripts in package.json as follows:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev:server": "nodemon --watch build --exec \"node build/bundle.js\"",
    "dev:build:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch"
  },
```

but I get the following error when I run npm run dev:server

```
[nodemon] 1.12.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: C:\Users\adinu\Documents\Dev\React Training Code\Udemy\Code\server\build/**/*
[nodemon] starting `node build/bundle.js`
'\"node build\bundle.js\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

If I run node build/bundle.js directly from the terminal, I get no errors.

I also checked the standard things like making sure nodejs is in the path, re-started the machine etc.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On MacOS Catalina, your code worked fine. I suggest removing the `\"` around `node build\bundle.js`, so your script looks like this:

```
"dev:build:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch"
```

That also worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

To make sure it works in windows, use the script as follows: remove the \" ... \" code around.

```js
"scripts": {
        "dev:server": "nodemon --watch build --exec node build/bundle.js",
        "dev:build:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch"
},
```